# Is it possible to use a taxonomy term as a category?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

(First question ever, yay!)

I'm new to WordPress and I'm having some concectual problems about taxonomies and terms.

> The names for the different groupings in a taxonomy are called terms. Using groupings of animals as an example, we might call one group "birds", and another group "fish". "Fish" and "birds" are terms in our taxonomy.

Using this example, I get that the taxonomy is the macro-category for the term. But is it possible to create a under-category for the term?
I mean, something like:

- Animals

  - Birds

    - Robin
    - Crow
    - ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    if(is_category()) {
    
        $breakpoint = 0;
        $thiscat = get_term( get_query_var('cat') , 'category' );
        $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.get_query_var('cat') );
    
        if(empty($subcategories) && $thiscat->parent != 0) {
            $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.$thiscat->parent.'' );
        }
?>
```

**use this code**